# Некорректная работа Linux (собранного в Buildroot) после запуска

Tags: linux, kernel

Собрал образ Linux в **Buildroot 2022.02**. После загрузки на реальном железе - нет отображения курсора мышки. Сама мышка работает (горит), но никаких видимых действий не происходит после нажатий на неё. Клавиатура не работает (Logitech Keyboard K120). Всё подключено через USB 2.0. Экран чёрный. Последнее, что вижу перед чёрным экраном - это запуск иксов. По нажатии кнопки выключения - экран сменяется терминалом и компьютер выключается. Не пойму, что я упустил в конфигах. Логи посмотреть так же не могу, так как не работает клавиатура для переключения на другой сеанс.

Прикладываю конфиги и то, что успел сфотографировать при выключении ПК.

[.config Buildroot](https://ftp.zhirov.website/trash/config_buildroot)

[.config Linux Kernel 4.19.209](https://ftp.zhirov.website/trash/config_linux)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: начни с отключения автозапуска иксов и попыток запустить их вручную